# Render appears to have z-fighting but render view doesn't

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm trying to render an orange juice bottle, but the render appears to have z-fighting but render view doesn't, and I don't even know what could be overlapping. Both have 32 samples. The first image is the viewport, and the second is the render. I saw similar issue to this (the person was also rendering orange juice which is funny) but it was because their normals were facing the wrong way, but mine are right.

[image: render view]

[image: render]

Comment: I would say that looks more like a refraction issue, although I have no idea why it would be present in the render only. Do you have a triangulate modifier that is enabled for the render, but disabled for the viewport, or something like that?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett No, I never added a triangulate modifier.

Comment: Yeah. I see that in the blend now. Any reason you're not using a Glass BSDF for your material?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Transmission set to 1 in the principles BSDF node seems to work exactly the same.

Answer (score 7):

You have a "backup bottle" hidden in the viewport. Items hidden in the viewport will still be visible in renders. This is why you see Z-fighting. Either delete the object or move it to a separate (disabled) collection.

[image: Bottle]

Comment: Agh thank you! Such a simple mistake! It's all good now.

Comment: No problem. Sometimes it just takes a second set of eyes to spot the small stuff. Glad I could help.